# React router won't navigate to nested -> nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So my Router looks like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route path={AUTH_BASE_ROUTE} element={<Auth />}>
        <Route index element={<SignIn />} />
        ...
        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={SIGN_IN} replace />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path={BASE_ROUTE} element={<ProtectedRoute component={<Main />} />}>
        <Route index element={<MainLayout />} />

        <Route path={MAIN_ROUTE} element={<MainLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />

          <Route path={DASHBOARD} element={<Dashboard />} />

          ...

          <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={DASHBOARD} replace />} />
        </Route>

        ...
        </Route>

        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={DASHBOARD} replace />} />
      </Route>

      <Route
        path='*'
        element={<Navigate to={!token ? AUTH_BASE_ROUTE : DASHBOARD} replace />}
      />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Routes are:

```
export const AUTH_BASE_ROUTE = `/auth`;
export const SIGN_IN = `${AUTH_BASE_ROUTE}/sign-in`;
export const BASE_ROUTE = `/main`;
export const MAIN_ROUTE = `${BASE_ROUTE}/office`;
export const DASHBOARD = `${MAIN_ROUTE}/dashboard`;
```

There are some context providers and an Outlet in Main

MainLayout is practically for layout and it has an Outlet which renders Dashboard and all other ... components.

I need to have them like that because of the architecture.

When I type empty route in url or /main/office or /main/office/dashboard it renders the Main, MainLayout and Dashboard as it should.

In the case where I just type /main in the url it renders just Main and MainLayout, no Dashboard?

Not sure what is the problem.

Comment: which version of react router ?

Comment: You have an `index` route in `main`. Why would it render every route? `<Route index element={<MainLayout />} />`

Comment: If the URL path is `"/main"` then only `Main` and `MainLayout` will be rendered since those are the routes the match and render `BASE_ROUTE`, i.e. `"/main"`. The `Dashboard` isn't rendered until the URL path matches `"/main/office"`.

Comment: @DrewReese So it doesn't matter if the Dashboard is the index route for MainLayout?
There is also that fallback route with * that routes to Dashboard...

Comment: No, I think it does matter. Like I said, when the path is `"/main"` then only `Main` and `MainLayout` components will render. The `Dashboard` component is rendered on a nested route, e.g. when the path is `"/main/office"` and `"/main/office/dashboard"`... according to your route constants. Fallbacks are only used when there isn't a defined path to match.

Comment: Can I somehow achieve the render of the Dashboard in this case?
One way would be to change the routes a bit for sure.. but is it possible to do it when the routes are organized like this?

Comment: How many different routes do you want the `Dashboard` component to render on? So you want ***both*** `MainLayout` and `Dashboard` to render on the index route for `BASE_ROUTE`, a.k.a. `"/main"`? Or in other words, you want `"/main"`, `"/main/office"`, and `"/main/office/dashboard"` to all render the same `Main`, `MainLayout`, and `Dashboard` components? All 3 routes render the same thing?

Comment: Yes.. I want both to render, where `Dashboard` is practically rendered in an `Outlet` in `MainLayout`. When I navigate  to `/` route that does happen, same as when I navigate to `/main/office`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit the post to include these layout components, and to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect live and fork from?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I resolved the issue by changing the routes a bit:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route path={AUTH_BASE_ROUTE} element={<Auth />}>
        <Route index element={<SignIn />} />
        ...
        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={SIGN_IN} replace />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path={BASE_ROUTE} element={<ProtectedRoute component={<Main />} />}>
        <Route path={MAIN_ROUTE} element={<MainLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />

          <Route path={DASHBOARD} element={<Dashboard />} />

          ...

          <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={DASHBOARD} replace />} />
        </Route>

        ...
        </Route>

        <Route path={BASE_ROUTE} element={<Navigate to={DASHBOARD} replace />} />

        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={DASHBOARD} replace />} />
      </Route>

      <Route
        path='*'
        element={<Navigate to={!token ? AUTH_BASE_ROUTE : DASHBOARD} replace />}
      />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

As you can see I removed the:

```
<Route index element={<MainLayout />} />
```

as it was loading that route without the `Outlet` content inside of `MainLayout` on just `/main`. And that behaviour is ok, because it doesn't know what Route to show in the `Outlet` inside of `MainLayout` as it doesn't have the next part in the route which matches of one the child routes that are wrapped with:

```
<Route path={MAIN_ROUTE} element={<MainLayout />}>
```

By adding:

```
<Route path={BASE_ROUTE} element={<Navigate to={DASHBOARD} replace />} />
```

it knows to navigate to `/main/office/dashboard` if the route is just `main` and with the

```
<Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={DASHBOARD} replace />} />
```

it will navigate to DASHBOARD in all other cases.